# How to compare individual characters in two strings in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to compare the first character of two different strings (and so on) to form a new string based on those results. This is what I've tried using, however its comparing every element of each list to each other.

```
def compare(a,b):
    s = ""
    for x in a:
        for y in b:
            if x == y:
                s+=str(x)
            else:
                s+=str(y)
```

It seems like such a simple question but I'm stuck.

Comment: What you've written simply copies y into s.
What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You're comparing every character in one string with every character in the other string, not just the corresponding characters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use zip:

```
def compare(a, b):
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        if x == y:
            ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you perhaps looking for something with logic similar to this?  It chooses the alphabetically earlier character from each input string:

```
def compare(a,b):
    s = ""
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] < b[i]:
            s+=str(a[i])
        else:
            s+=str(b[i])
    return s

print compare ("seven", "eight")
```

Output:

```
eegen
```

---

The one-line version of this is

```
return ''.join(a[i] if a[i] < b[i] else b[i] for i in range(len(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input(x)
input(y)
cnt = 0
 for char_val in x:
   if b[cnt] == char_val:
      print("match")
   else:
      print("mis-match")
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some explanation as though why this answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete function

```
def compare_strings(a,b):
    result = True
    if len(a) != len(b): print('string lengths do not match!')
    for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
        if x != y:
            print(f'char miss-match {x,y} in element {i}')
            result = False
    if result: print('strings match!')
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def twoStrings(s1, s2):
for i in range(len(s1)):
    for j in range(len(s2)):
        if s2[j] == s1[i]:
            return 'YES'
return 'NO'
```

Comment: format can be improved (the `return` and `for` keywords are on the same column than `def`) and it's always better to add a little explanation with code

Answer (score 0):

We can write simple and easy method to compare similar letters in two strings

```
def compare(a,b):
    s = ""
    t=""
    for x in a:
        for y in b:
            if x == y:
                t=x
        s=s+t
    print(s)

compare("xyz","axy")
```

Here first `for loop` will compare each letters in string and display all similar character.